# Can we open home router in terminal

Tags: router

Can we contact home router in terminal. I need to do lot of manual changes to router which are not available in typical webserver (192.168.0.1). My router is dlink 600L .

Answer (score 3):

Many SOHO routers have a `telnet` interface, but this feature is often ommited in manuals. Maybe yours does it too. You can try to connect using a telnet client:

```
telnet 192.168.0.1
```

If you're using Windows, then you most likely don't have `telnet` installed. You can add it in the *Turn Windows features on or off* window:

[image: Windows feature list with Telnet client checked]

Or you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) instead.

Linux and OS X have telnet installed by default (as far as I know).

Bad news is: this interface rarely exposes any extra features. You can try, though, but be careful, because oftentimes seemingly innocent features can do something unexpected, for example reset router to factory defaults.

Some SOHO network devices can be [hacked to support extra features](https://spritesmods.com/?art=rtl8366sb), but it requires **a lot** of skill and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

No. Per the [manual](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-600L/REVA/DIR-600L_MANUAL_1.00_EN.PDF), the only administration option on that model is the web interface. it does not ship with SSH or Telnet servers running.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Manual](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-600L/REVB/DIR-600L_REVB_MANUAL_1.00_EN.PDF), the only configuration methods are web based:

> There are a couple different ways you can configure your router to
>   connect to the Internet and connect to your clients:
>
> - D-Link Easy Setup Wizard - This wizard will launch if you log into the router for the first time. See below.
> - Manual Setup - Log into the router and manually configure your router (advanced users only).

The "manual setup" instructions start with:

> To access the configuration utility, open a *web-browser* such as Internet
>   Explorer and enter the IP address of the router (http://192.168.0.1)